# Merge 'regular' Google account calendar with a Google Apps for your domain calendar

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

I have a 'regular' Gmail account, and a Google Apps for your domain account through one of my clients.

I use the calendars in both accounts, but there seems to be no good way to view events from both accounts in a single page.

Comment: I think you can share your Google apps account's calendar with the normal account. That way you can view both the calendar from the regular account's calendar. Try it.

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly. I actually shared both calenders both ways, so I can see events from both no matter which one I'm in. Go ahead and put this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share your Google Apps account's calendar with the regular account. That way you can view both of them from the regular account's calendar. Or vice-versa.